# SignalR.Client: Console client not receive event like browser client

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a asp.net mvc hub with one 'Send' method. In addition I have 2 clients: chrome browser and console app.

When i send message to 'MyHub' from console to 'Send' method everything works as expected, 'broadcastMessage' event get messages (console and browser).

When I initiate to clients from mvc server by

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
```

Only the browser receives the event "broadcastMessage" but console client not received any message.

What I did wrong?

asp.net mvc Hub:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{  
    public void Send(string param)
    { 
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage($" param: {param}"); 
    } 
}
```

console app:

```
public void OnBroadcastMessage(Action<string> action)
{
    _myHub.On<string>("broadcastMessage", param =>
    {
        ...
    });
}
```